# Bootstrap 4 layout row first vs column first?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Most grid layout examples in Bootstrap 4 put columns inside rows.  Is it wrong to put rows inside columns ? Like this,

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so since it's valid to have rows inside columns and vice versa, what is the better approach, i.e. thinking columns first or thinking rows when laying out your grids?

Comment: yes, except content must go inside the `col`, and not directly in the `row`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's totally valid to use nested columns/row. Just be sure to always use a column inside a row. Else you'll get unexpected layouts.

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <!-- Your content goes here -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly valid approach. Consider the example below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6"></div>
      <div class="col-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-3"></div>
      <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [x]-col-[y] classes are all percentage based for widths. Go nuts with the nesting! Just make sure you wrap them in a row div else you'll get some funky margins